# Проблема с массивами в lua (corona sdk))

Tags: массивы, lua, coronasdk

Допустим, нужно исходя из значения переменной, принтить в консоль содержимое ячейки массива. Те
как-то так:

```
if(my_var>=0)then
     text = array[my_var]
     print(text)
end
```

Как это сделать? На мой вариант ругается. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В lua нет массивов и объектов. Вместо них используется обобщённый тип - [таблицы](http://lua-users.org/wiki/TablesTutorial).

Ваш пример рабочий.

```lua
local my_var = 1
local array = {"one", "two"} -- то же, что и {[1] = "one", [2] = "two"}

if (my_var >= 0) then
  local text = array[my_var]
  print(text) -- one
end
```

Comment: Спасибо! Я видимо не в то место копать стал)